# Command to get full configuration in Fortianalyzer

Tags: fortigate, fortinet

Could anyone please tell me how to get the full configuration info in Fortianalyzer ver 6.0.6. 
 I’m an entry level of a network engineer. 
It would be nice if you can help me with simple English.

Thank you.

Chie

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can pull the configuration using FTP, SFTP or SCP, or copy it to a server using

```
execute backup all-settings {ftp | sftp} <server IP address> <path/filename to the server> <user name on server> <password> [cryptpasswd]
execute backup all-settings scp <server IP address> <path/filename to the server> <user name on server> <SSH certificate> <crptpassrd>
```

On the console you can run

```
show full-configuration
```

or just

```
show
```

as well. (You might need to set context by `config global` beforehand.)

Comment: Thank you for your help. But the command “show full configuration” does not work. I have been looking for a right command on the internet for 1 hour. ..

Comment: You might need to get into the appropriate context - try `config global` before.